# What is a 'Tomato based router'?

Tags: networking, router, proxy

Could someone please explain what this diagram means?
Most importantly the 'Tomato based router'.

[image: diagram]

[Source.](https://github.com/corporate-gadfly/Tunlr-Clone)

Comment: [tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tomato based router is a router based on the "Tomato" distribution - an aftermarket linux distribution which works with a number of routers and makes them more functional.